# Modify BIOS configuration on several computers

Tags: update, bios

I have quite a few computers that I need to modify some parameters on the BIOS (American Megatrends v.5.12). Is there a way to save this configuration (to a pendrive, for example) and load that on the other computers? or maybe even modifying via network or on the command line?

Answer (score 1):

It depend on the computer manufacturer as it's push via their out of band utility.

HP got tool to do so but it depend on the brand. There is an [exemple](https://www.danielengberg.com/hp-bios-configuration-utility-sccm/) for HP.

There for other brand;

HP  – [HP BIOS Configuration Utility (BCU)](https://support.lenovo.com/se/sv/solutions/ht100612)

DELL –  [DELL Command Configure Toolkit (CCTK)](https://support.lenovo.com/se/sv/solutions/ht100612)

Lenovo – [Lenovo WMI scripts](https://support.lenovo.com/se/sv/solutions/ht100612)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. But the manufacturer barely provides a datasheet, so I doubt there would be such a tool for it. Do you know if there is any standard tool that could work for BIOS in general (or for American megatrends specifically)?

Comment: @user No sorry, its all manual task from what I seen.. and I seen many post that told it's the manufacturer responsability to provide such tool.. What brand you have ?